# Should i use webpack or create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

Should i use webpack or create-react-app to initialize my react app? Is there any advantage of using webpack over create-react-app?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. Webpack is not capable of _"initialising"_ a react app, that's what CRA does. Also, projects created with CRA use Webpack by default

Comment: @Phil yeah i know that but with CRA we cannot have full control over the webpack and if we create react app from scratch using webpack we will have more control over how our js is bundled

Comment: But that's not what you're asking in your question. Also you can always eject the webpack config from a CRA project

Comment: Even if your question was clear (which it is not), opinion based questions are [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow

Answer (score 3):

Create react app abstracts the configuration does not allow you change it unless you eject.
Using webpack does require knowledge of webpack and does allow complete control over your environment.

CRA is best suited for projects where you the requirements does not need you to change settings , if you need control and need to change things it is best to use Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

First, *Webpack is a build tool*, which uses configuration to (as an example) transpile Typescript to JavaScript, bundle SASS, LESS files, bundle SVG files etc.

*Create React App* is a React boilerplate that *uses* Babel and Webpack under the hood, with configurations already in place for the *most common scenarios*, so you don't have to worry about it.

It is not clear from your question, what *initialization* means. I can only assume that you mean to bootstrap an application with a moderately easy learning curve. If that is the case, CRA is the way to go.